# How to use PHP in angular project

Tags: php, angular

I was learning angular2, Now I have one doubt. How to use PHP in Angular 2? 
Because Angular 2 files are .html type. So how to use it?

Answer (score -1):

The HTML files would call PHP API(.php files), to get response and display accordingly.

For example:

```
<script>
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('country.php').success(function(data) {
      $scope.countries = data;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not necessary + it's angularJs

Answer (score -1):

You should think differently, what should I use as front end & back end ? Angular works with webservices and API. So in most cases, you'll need to build an API. I would suggest you ExpressJS & Node or even an ElasticSearch Database to first understand APIs.

Useful link : https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html